# Probability of geometric random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-distributions, expected-value

Problem: A bag contains  $K$  blue balls and $N−K$ red balls. Find the expected number of blue balls observed when $n$ balls are randomly drawn.

Trying to figure out how to solve and there are 4 options:

- $n\frac{K}{N}$
- $(n-1)\frac{K}{N}$
- $(n-1)\frac{K-1}{N-1}$
- $(n)\frac{K-1}{N-1}$

When you pick ball 1 it would have $p(K)=\frac{K}{N}$.  How do you find the $p(K)$ when the $p(K)$ keeps decreasing?  Do you need to assume that $n$ decreases also? My first guess would be that the answer is: $(n-1)\frac{K-1}{N-1}$.  But that is wrong.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your distribution is not a geometric but it can by an Hypergeometric or a Binomial, it depends if you draw the balls without or with replacement, respectively.

In both cases, the Expectation of the number of Blue balls drawn is $n\frac{K}{N}$

Comment: Can you do step by step to get to that realization for me?

Comment: @which kind of sampling do you prefer? with or without replacement?

Comment: Either or both will do

Comment: @Fototekt : get a look here: https://www.fulviofrisone.com/attachments/article/446/Introduction%20to%20the%20theory%20of%20statistics%20by%20MOOD.pdf. Theorem 3 on page 89 (with replacement) and Theorem 5 on page 91 (without replacement)